# Delete Initial Branch Commit

Tags: git, branch

I was working in a branch in a linear situation to master, like so:

```
a ---> b[master] ---> c ---> d[branch]
```

However I noticed that `b` had a mistake in its message so I amended it. The problem is that Git duplicated the commit, to preserve the parent of the branch, resulting in this:

```
a -+-> b'[master]
   |
   +-> b ---> c ---> d[branch]
```

In this case `b'` has the correct message and `b` the incorrect (old) one. How can I delete `b` while setting `b'` as `c`'s parent?

Comment: Side note: Git duplicates `b` to `b'` not "to preserve the parent", but rather because it *has to*: the identity (SHA-1 hash) of any object in Git is the hash of all the data in that object. Changing anything about a commit, including the message text, results in a new (different) commit. Git works by always adding new stuff, without discarding existing stuff, and when you rebase `branch` you will copy `c` and `d` to `c'` (`c'` = `c` but with `b'` as parent) and `d'` (`d` but with `c'` as parent).  The old (`b--c--d`) chain lives on, saved via reflogs, until the reflog entries expire.

Comment: @torek thank you very much for the in-deep explanation. I wasn't sure in writing that indeed. Now I see better how it works internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rebase the master back to the branch and delete `b`.  On your branch do `git rebase -i master`.  You should be given a list of commits `b`, `c` and `d`.  Delete `b` from this list which will cause the commit to be removed and `b'` will be in the history also.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, only commit `c` and `d` appeared on the list, however I proceeded anyway and it successfully changed the tree as I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, git recognized that `b` was no longer needed and dropped it.  I wasn't 100% sure that that was going to be the case.